# Many2one and One2Many Errors in Odoo python

Tags: python, one-to-many, multiple-inheritance, many-to-one, odoo-13

I got this problem where I had inherited a class with sale.order and the other class is just a __name or associated with it.

```
class module_A(models.Model):
       _name='new.module_a'
      
       sale_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='sale.order')
       currency_id = fields.Many2one('res.currency',     string="currency")
       price_value = fields.Monetary(related="sale_id.total_price", string="Initial Price value",
                                          currency_field="currency_id")

class module_B(models.Model):
       
    _inherit = 'sale.order'
    module_id = fields.One2many(string="module A",
                                    comodel_name='new.module_a', inverse_name='sale_id')
    total_price = fields.Monetary(string="Price Initial", store=True, readonly=True, compute='_amount_all',
                                  tracking=4)
    amount_untaxed = fields.Monetary(string="Untaxed Amount", store=True, readonly=True, compute='_amount_all',
                                     tracking=5)
    amount_tax = fields.Monetary(string="Taxes", store=True, readonly=True, compute='_amount_all')

    @api.depends('order_line.price_total')
    def _amount_all(self):
        for order in self:
            amount_untaxed = amount_tax = 0.0
            for line in order.order_line:
                amount_untaxed += line.price_subtotal
                amount_tax += line.price_tax

            total_price = amount_tax + amount_untaxed
            print(total_price)
            order.update({
                'amount_untaxed': amount_untaxed,
                'amount_tax': amount_tax,
                'amount_total': amount_untaxed + amount_tax,
                'total_price': amount_untaxed + amount_tax,
            })
```

Problems:
1. In the tree view, the price_value is 0. meaning it didn't get the values from the total_price after the related it with sale_id. I don't know why.

but when I separated it with the tree_view. The price is shown. 
[image]

xml:

```
<field name="module_id"/>
         tree view
             control
             field name="price_value" <- field in module A

    <group>
        <field name="total_price"/> <- field in module B
```

Note: The fields cannot be interchanged since total_price will be looking at the inherited sale.order while price_value does not exist in module_b.

2. If I total all values, I need also values from class module_A and put it in module_B. This is a big problem since it will not work because both uses the same columns and tables.
3. I have to add a subtotal in every item in the tree view which I have to take the number 2 problem in it. Example calculate total values in class module_A and get the values from A to B so that I can display it in view.

Initial price value are still zero.

[image]

Comment: Note: The calculations in module_B works as it is shown in the picture with 141k but the initial price in tree is still 0.

Answer (score 0):

On the model `_name='new.module_a'` set the `sale_id` field `one2many` to many2one,

```
sale_id = fields.Many2one('sale.order', string="Sale")
```

Thanks

Comment: Does not work. If I choose that one, I could not create quotation. 

"Sorry, you are not allowed to access documents of type 'new.module_a' (new.module_a). No group currently allows this operation

Comment: @William check the access right for this model - new.module_a. Seem you have not added them in the security file.

Comment: I had already change the security. Still does not work. I had edit everything from One2Many to Many2one. Initial Price is still zero.

Comment: Does not work at all. Still Initial Price is zero. I had already put this on a readonly field.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to this question. Just to make the architect_ids as depending in api.depends to access the fields in module A.